# GDM doesn't start - Kali Linux

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, runlevel, gdm3

I've been having this problem since I installed genuine Nvidia GeForce drivers for my graphics card.

My system boots normally, but when the login screen should show only black screen shows.

The only solution to start gdm3 is to restart X server by typing `telinit 3; telinit 5`. Then gdm3 starts normally.

Did anyone had the same problem, and, if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your default run level, AFAIK to start gui you need to be on run level 5

check via `runlevel` command.

you can also insert runlevel in grub.cfg, open as root

> /boot/grub/grub.cfg

find line start with
`linux /boot/... root=... ......`

insert 5 at last of it, like
`linux /boot/... root=... ...... 5`

save, reboot.